# file does not exist error in django while updating a column in database

Tags: python, sql, database, django

I am working with django.

my models.py

```
class I(models.Model):
    pic = models.FileField(#upload image)

class Pl(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(I)
```

This is my views file

```
user=request.user
s_p = Pl.objects.filter(id=user.id)
if request.method=='POST':
    pic = request.FILES.get('profile_picture')
    temp = IsNotNullString(pic)
    if (temp==1):
        I_object = I(pic=pic)
        I_object.save()
        s_p.update(picture_id=I_object.id)
```

This shows me a error that *Pl has no field named 'picture_id'* . When i check the database the I_object is been saved.

I am new in django and i dont know what is the mistake i am making
Hope you understand the problem.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean `s_p.update(picture__id=I_object.id)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace following line:

```
s_p.update(picture_id=I_object.id)
```

with:

```
s_p.update(picture=I_object)
```